Change nextjs server action to communicate in text/json instead of text/plain
One of the application I am working on is being deployed to Intranet and from client I got to know that they have WAF which disabled all the text/plain request for some security reason. I wasn't aware on the potential security risk for this so I did a little digging and found out this article
https://blog.sicuranext.com/why-text-plain-is-evil-for-web-application-firewall-and-input-validation/
I did a long discussion and seems like they have no intention of disabling check for our particular server. So I want to know if it's possible to change the communication method used by nextjs server actions. So far I got multiple routes they have blocked
So for this all I could find out is that when sending request it sends like this
accept: text/x-component
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 2
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8

Is there any other workaround?
